Confused Ant II (from Quant Questions) Expected Value
The question goes as such
An ant walks the corner of a 3D cube and moves to one of the three adjacent vertices with equal probability at each step. Find the expected number of steps needed for the ant to return to the vertex it started at.
Here is my reasoning
Suppose the ant starts at $(0,0,0)$
Let $A$ be the max number of steps to return point and let $X$ be the number of steps from needed for ant to return to (0,0,0)
$$E[X| A=1] = \frac{1}{3} (1) + \frac{2}{3}(1+E[X| A=2]) = 7$$
$$E[X|A= 2] = \frac{1}{3} (1+E[X|A= 3]) + \frac{2}{3} (1+E[X|A =1])  = 9$$
$$E[X|A =3] = (1+E[X|A = 2]) = 10$$
However, it seems that I am wrong. Is there plausible cause that I am over/under counting?
Edit: As suggested by lulu in the comments. I should have let $X_i$ be the number of steps needed for the ant to return to $(0,0,0)$ when the ant is $i$ steps away.
And the expected value we are finding for is $$E[X] = 1+E[X_i]$$
This gives us the final answer of $E[X] = 1 +7 = 8$

This is hard to follow.  What does $Pr(A=1)$ mean?  I suggest:  aside from the special node, there are three types of nodes, depending on the distance from the special one.  Let $E_i$ be the expected number of steps it takes to get home given that you are a distance $i$ away.  Write down a linear system satisfied by the $E_i$ and solve.

@lulu Thank you. In this case, A= k refers to the event that the ant is k units away from the vertex. Which in this case it would be 1,2 or 3 units away. I have done your method as shown above.
For instance, if the ant is 1 unit away from the starting point,  1/3 of the time I would go back to the starting point and 2/3 of the time I would be moving 1 unit further (i.e I would be 2 units away from starting point). In essence, that would be
E[X| A=1] = 1/3 (1) + 2/3 (1+E[X| A=2])

Formatting would help.  here is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

I get $E_1=1+\frac 23\times E_2$, $E_2=+\frac {2E_1+E_3}3$, $E_3=1+E_2$ for the linear system.  That appears you match what you wrote for $E[X,|,A=1]$ at least but my system yields $E_1=7$ (and $E_2=9, E_3=10$).

In my reading, $E_1$ is the desired answer.  The phrasing is a bit ambiguous, but I read the problem as asking "given that the ant has moved once (hence is now at a vertex exactly $1$ away from home), what is the expected number of moves needed to get home?"  and that is the definition of $E_1$.  So I think the answer is $7$.  Other readings might be possible, but I don't see one that gets me to $8.25$
